# Dynamically change the locale in Angular 7 at runtime without having to reload the app

Tags: angular, typescript, localization, angular7, setlocale

I am trying to change Locale_Id in my angular app at the runtime but must use `window.location.reload()` to fire changes at locale.

I want to change locale without reloading my app.

here is my code:

#### app.module

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { LocaleService} from "./services/locale.service";

@NgModule({
    imports: [//imports],
    providers: [
        {provide: LOCALE_ID,
         deps: [LocaleService],
         useFactory: (LocaleService: { locale: string; }) => LocaleService.locale
        }
    ]})
```

#### locale.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeEnglish from '@angular/common/locales/en';
import localeArabic from '@angular/common/locales/ar';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class LocaleService{

    private _locale: string;

    set locale(value: string) {
        this._locale = value;
    }
    get locale(): string {
        return this._locale || 'en';
    }

    registerCulture(culture: string) {
        if (!culture) {
            return;
        }
        this.locale = culture;

        switch (culture) {
            case 'en': {
                registerLocaleData(localeEnglish);
                break;
            }
            case 'ar': {
                registerLocaleData(localeArabic);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### app.component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LocaleService} from "./services/locale.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <p>Choose language:</p>
    <button (click)="english()">English</button>
    <button (click)="arabic()">Arabic</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private session: LocaleService) {}

  english() {
    this.session.registerCulture('en');
    window.location.reload(); // <-- I don't want to use reload
  }

  arabic() {
    this.session.registerCulture('ar');
    window.location.reload(); // <-- I don't want to use reload
  }
}
```

Comment: what about traditiona way when you have baseHref='/ar/': https://angular.io/guide/i18n#build-for-multiple-locales

Comment: It is not suitable for you?

Comment: I am trying to implement  this in angular 8 but doesn't work. even in page refresh. only work if i run `ng serve --configuration=de`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need to reload, but just delay a little to ending `registerCulture`

for example:

```
english() {
    spinner.show();  // <-- start any loader
    setTimeout(() => {
            this.session.registerCulture('en');
            spinner.hide();  // <-- stop the loader
          }, 1000);    
    // window.location.reload();
  }
```